# How to get this strange logic?

Tags: design-patterns

Given, Input = {2,4,1,6}

Output = It is a pattern printed as,

```
       *
       *
   *   *
   *   *
 * *   *
 * * * *
```

what is the logic behind this pattern?(There may or may not be spaces between the stars.)

Comment: Can you, please, add the programming language you use? And at least show us what you have tried?

Comment: You could try the easier problem of having the lines extend left to right instead of bottom up, then try to reapply the logic.

Comment: you can try in any language like c or java @CodeNotFound

Answer (score 1):

Find out the maximum number in the array. Now loop from that number to 0 and check every element of the array. If it is equal to the ith number then print * and decrease the number in the array. Of not print space.

Pseudo code:

```
max = maximum in array
for i=max to 0:
    for j=0 to the array_size:
        if arr[j]==i:
             print(*)
             arr[j]--
        else:
            print(" ")
```